# How to fix an Intent for calendar not adding it as an all day event

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, calendar

I am trying to add a button to my app that allows someone to add an assignment to their calendar. I am doing this using an Intent and CalendarContract. Everything is working correctly, in that it launches the calendar app in the add an event state and all of the information is in the correct field and displaying properly. The only thing that I am having a problem with is the

```
CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY to true
```

isn't making it default to an all day event.

I have tried separating it out into multiple .putExtra statements, as well as tried individual components, but none of that seems to make any difference.

```
startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT)
                    .setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI)
                    .setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/event")
                    .putExtras(
                            bundleOf(
                                    CalendarContract.Events.TITLE to assignment.getItemText(),
                                    CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION to "${assignment.beginDate.takeIf { it != null }?.let { 
                                        "${getString(R.string.start_date)}: ${it.format("MMM dd, h:mm a")}\n\n"} ?: ""}${getString(R.string.due_date)}: ${assignment.dueDate.format("MMM dd, h:mm a")}\n\n${assignment.getDetailText()}",
                                    // If there is just one time, put it in for both so that the generated event in the calendar app has logical and related start/end times
                                    CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME to (assignment.beginDate?.time ?: assignment.dueDate.time),
                                    CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME to assignment.dueDate.time,
                                    CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY to true
                            )
                    )
            )
```

I expected that this would allow me to go to add an event that has all day selected but it doesn't default to that.

I have noticed that this issue only occurs with Google Calendar

Any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the current version of Android's integration with Google Calendar. Hopefully they will have a bug fix out in a patch release soon. It's definitely working in all other calendars that I've tested